# LASSO for two types of variables: optimal tuning?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, lasso, regularization

I have a location and scale linear regression model:

$$y_j = x_j^T\beta + e_j,$$

where $e_j\sim N(0,\sigma_j)$, and $\sigma_j = \exp(x_j^T\theta)$, $j=1,...,n$, $x_j \in{\mathbb R}_p$, $\beta \in{\mathbb R}_p$ ,$\theta \in{\mathbb R}_p$.

I would like to do penalized maximum likelihood estimation for some penalties $p_{\lambda_1}(\beta)$, $p_{\lambda_2}(\theta)$ (e.g. LASSO) and I have the impression that the tuning parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ should be different in general. How can I choose these tuning parameters, for example, for the LASSO penalties?

$$p_{\lambda_1}(\beta) = \lambda_1 \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \beta_i\vert. $$

$$p_{\lambda_2}(\beta) = \lambda_2 \sum_{i=1}^p \vert \theta_i\vert. $$

Comment: what's your loss function here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do cross-validation to choose the optimal parameter values.

You basically choose a grid for $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ - theoretically this can be $(\mathbb{R}^{+},\mathbb{R}^{+})$ practically if you use a machine you will have to specify a maximum value and a step.

Afterwards, for each combination, you compute the cross validation mean square error. You then select the $\lambda$'s that gave you the lowest error.

Cross validation details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate your *comment*?

Comment: Thanks, a bit superficial, but still of some help.